# WebLogic status Starting and never changes

Tags: java, weblogic, application-server

I am developing a Java Application that is on Oracle WebLogic server, but when it starts comes with the logs:

```
    JAVA Memory arguments: -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=48m  -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
.
WLS Start Mode=Development
.
CLASSPATH=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1036\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_oepe180\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_ocp371\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_adfr1111\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\JDK160~1\lib\tools.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic_sp.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\features\weblogic.server.modules_10.3.6.0.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\webservices.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\ORGAPA~1.1/lib/ant-all.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\NETSFA~1.0_1/lib/ant-contrib.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\common\derby\lib\derbyclient.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\xqrl.jar
.
PATH=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1036\profiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_oepe180\profiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_ocp371\profiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_adfr1111\profiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\native\win\32;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\ORGAPA~1.1\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\JDK160~1\jre\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\JDK160~1\bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_91/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_91/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_91/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9\\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\eclipse-mars;;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\native\win\32\oci920_8
.
***************************************************
*  To start WebLogic Server, use a username and   *
*  password assigned to an admin-level user.  For *
*  server administration, use the WebLogic Server *
*  console at http:\\hostname:port\console        *
***************************************************
starting weblogic with Java version:
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8453
java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.4-b02, mixed mode)
Starting WLS with line:
C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\JDK160~1\bin\java -client -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8453,server=y,suspend=n -Djava.compiler=NONE  -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=48m  -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Dweblogic.Name=AdminServer -Djava.security.policy=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic.policy  -Xverify:none  -ea -da:com.bea... -da:javelin... -da:weblogic... -ea:com.bea.wli... -ea:com.bea.broker... -ea:com.bea.sbconsole... -Dplatform.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3 -Dwls.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server -Dweblogic.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server   -Dweblogic.management.discover=true  -Dwlw.iterativeDev= -Dwlw.testConsole= -Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole= -Dweblogic.ext.dirs=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1036\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_oepe180\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_ocp371\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_adfr1111\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath  weblogic.Server
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8453
<07/06/2016 18h08min02s BRT> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090905> <Disabling CryptoJ JCE Provider self-integrity check for better startup performance. To enable this check, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultJCEVerification=true> 
<07/06/2016 18h08min02s BRT> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090906> <Changing the default Random Number Generator in RSA CryptoJ from ECDRBG to FIPS186PRNG. To disable this change, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultPRNG=true> 
<07/06/2016 18h08min02s BRT> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000377> <Starting WebLogic Server with Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM Version 20.4-b02 from Sun Microsystems Inc.> 
<07/06/2016 18h08min03s BRT> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141107> <Version: WebLogic Server 10.3.6.0  Tue Nov 15 08:52:36 PST 2011 1441050 > 
<07/06/2016 18h08min04s BRT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING> 
<07/06/2016 18h08min04s BRT> <Info> <WorkManager> <BEA-002900> <Initializing self-tuning thread pool> 
<07/06/2016 18h08min04s BRT> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320400> <The log file C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\sampleApplication\servers\AdminServer\logs\AdminServer.log will be rotated. Reopen the log file if tailing has stopped. This can happen on some platforms like Windows.> 
<07/06/2016 18h08min04s BRT> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320401> <The log file has been rotated to C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\sampleApplication\servers\AdminServer\logs\AdminServer.log00092. Log messages will continue to be logged in C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\sampleApplication\servers\AdminServer\logs\AdminServer.log.> 
<07/06/2016 18h08min04s BRT> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170019> <The server log file C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\sampleApplication\servers\AdminServer\logs\AdminServer.log is opened. All server side log events will be written to this file.> 
<07/06/2016 18h08min05s BRT> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090082> <Security initializing using security realm myrealm.> 
<07/06/2016 18h08min06s BRT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STANDBY> 
<07/06/2016 18h08min06s BRT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING>
```

And then, it starts my application, and it is working very fine, but I can't access weblogic console and if I want to stop it, I have to kill de proccess manually.

It looks like my app starts but don't "tell" the server its running, so the server keeps waiting it to start.

I was looking at weblogic configurations and put a file named weblogic.xml in my WEB-INF directory looking as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.3/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
</weblogic-web-app>
```

But it also doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How have you deployed the code? Using wlst i guess or weblogic deployer as you cannot access the console.
I suppose you know about Admin and managed servers. If it is just the admin server (the logs say so) and you have targeted your code to the same, the admin server has to get into running mode else your application wouldn't have responded.
I would suggest looking for rotated logs in the same directory where you got this log from. 
I can see that your WLS is actually an OSB domain from the libraries. Are you sure you are hitting the right port of the admin server with a /console at the end?
If it is the command prompt output that you have pasted, I would suggest increasing the max perm size to 256M since it is trying to bring up the sbconsole as well and these class loadings would occupy quite a bit of PERMGEN space.
Additionally, you can do a netstat and find on "Listening" to see what all HTTP ports are available and you can try with the same. Please try both with localhost and your machine IP in the url.
Please try these and let me know what you experienced.

Comment: You can also take several thread dumps to see what the server is doing. To do so, press CTRL + Pause in the window shell where your server is running. You can do the same using jconsole.